Как настроить синхронизацию времени в VirtualBox на Debian без GUI с основной операционной системой(Windows 10)?
Такое впечатление, что Debian ни с чем не синхронизирует время, а само его считает, только намного медленнее. То есть, секунда длиться гораздо дольше, чем надо. По этому вопросу в интернете очень мало информации. Я пробовал синхронизировать время через NTP, но так ничего и не получилось. Пробовал вводить такую команду: VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution" 0, но консоль выдает ошибку о том, что команды не существует. Вопрос: как синхронизировать время гостевой операционной системы с основной? Буду благодарен любым советам!
